# Haskell Equivalent Types - Tell GHCI that one type is the same as another after the type has already been declared

Tags: haskell

I have the following code that I am working with in a Module:

```
module WorkingModule (GlobalDesignChoices(...), MyComponentName(...)) where
   
data GlobalDesignChoices = GlobalDesignChoices {
   myComponentName :: MyComponentName
}
    
class RenderString a where
        showString :: a -> String 

data MyComponentName = MyInput | MyOutput

instance RenderString MyComponentName where
  showString MyInput = "the_input" 
  showString MyInput = "the_output"
```

In another Module I have the following code (section of the file):

```
import WorkingModule

type Name = String

getFormat :: IrrelevantType
getFormat = do
  g <- get
  getParameters "the_input" OtherInput1 OtherInput2

getParameters :: Name -> ParamType -> ParamType2 -> IrrelevantType
```

What I am trying to do is set up the WorkingModule code so that I can simply replace "the_input" in the second module with MyInput:

```
getFormat :: IrrelevantType
getFormat = do
  g <- get
  getParameters MyInput OtherInput1 OtherInput2
```

However I currently get an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘MyComponentName’ with ‘[Char]’
       Expected type: Name
         Actual type: MyComponentName
```

How can I set up the code in the WorkingModule so that the system knows that MyComponentName is (interchangeable with) Name? I cannot make other modifications to the other Module, besides the string replacement above. I tried adding `type MyComponentName = Name` but got the obvious error of `Multiple declarations of ‘MyComponentName’`

Comment: `MyComponentName` is not interchangeable with `Name` though, as you've shown it here. `Name` is an alias for `String`, which is a list of characters; there are an infinite number of possible values of this type . `MyComponentName` is explicitly declared to allow only two possible values: `MyInput` and `MyOutput`. You've already written `renderString` to convert `MyComponentNane` to `String` (which is `Name`). You could parse corresponding strings back to `MyComponentName` (but would have to handle the possibility of failure). But there's no way they can be interchangeable.

Comment: The restriction of being able to make one specific change to a module, but no others, seems odd. can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm understanding the question, you're trying to change the behaviour of a module without changing its source code. The type `Name` is compiled in to the module as an alias to `String` (a.ka. `[Char]`), and Haskell provides no way to override things like this outside of the source file.